# Pandas dataframe: calculating variation over years

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this

```
Years {2000, ..., 2001, ..., 2002, ...}
product {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ...}
price $ {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, ...}
```

So, I have many products, with different prices over the years for each of them
I'd like to compute the yearly evolution for each product year after year

I can do that with a for loop where for each row I look for the product and the year+1 to get the price but it sounds heavy and long to execute.

is there a better way to do this ?

the best (for later purposes) would be to get something like that

```
Years {2000, ..., 2001, ..., 2002, ...}
product {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ...}
price $ {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, ...}
next price $ {11, 13, 14, 12, 14, ...}
```

Finally I know  that product A for year 2000 has a price of $10 and the next price (2001) of $11

hope you understand me !
Thank you all in advance
AE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Years': [2000]*4+[2001]*2+[2000]*2+[2001]*2+[2002]*4,
                   'Product': [np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']) for _ in range(0, 14)],
                   'Price': np.random.uniform(1,5, size=14)})

res = df.sort_values('Years').set_index('Years').groupby('Product').apply(lambda x: x['Price'].diff())

Product  Years
A        2001          NaN
B        2001          NaN
         2001     3.176459
         2002    -0.743620
C        2000          NaN
         2000     1.450093
         2001    -0.040187
         2002    -3.237749
D        2000          NaN
         2000    -0.670978
         2000     0.434457
         2000     0.280269
         2002    -0.002989
         2002     2.671679
```

Comment: perfect thanks !
I can manage with diff() to get the next price for other computation.

Comment: Great! Happy to have helped.